# Role of the remainder operator to determine an index in an hash algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am studying the hash algorithm in a book and come across this line

> the index is 3 + 2 + 17 % 10 = 22 % 10 = 2

I can understand that is referring that the index is 2, and the `%` is a remainder, but is too much esoteric to understand.

Here below the context where is explained where this index comes from, namely is an exercise of the book

> Suppose you have these four hash functions that work with strings: A.
>   Return “1” for all input. B. Use the length of the string as the
>   index. C. Use the first character of the string as the index. So, all
>   strings starting with a are hashed together, and so on. D. Map every
>   letter to a prime number: a = 2, b = 3, c = 5, d = 7, e = 11, and so
>   on. For a string, the hash function is the sum of all the characters
>   modulo the size of the hash. For example, if your hash size is 10, and
>   the string is “bag”, the index is 3 + 2 + 17 % 10 = 22 % 10 = 2. For
>   each of the following examples, which hash functions would provide a
>   good distribution? Assume a hash table size of 10 slots.
>   5.5 A phonebook where the keys are names and values are phone numbers. The names are as follows: Esther, Ben, Bob, and Dan. Answer: Hash
>   functions C and D would give a good distribution.

Comment: Remainder is used so that hash values remain not too large to handle efficiently

Comment: @Photon: no, this is not the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example shows 4 hash-functions (A-D). Each of the functions return a value used to place the word (string) in a bucket.

A. All words will go to same bucket, the function returns 1. There is not a good distribution.

B. All words will be sorted on the length of the string. There will be not be many words in the first bucket, only "a" or "I" as far as I can think of. Where as buckets 3-6 will be heavily occupied.

C. now the words are sorted on the first letter, we have 26 letters in the alphabet but not all words are evenly presented (words starting with x is way less than words starting with h)

D. has most likely the best distribution as it uses prime numbers. The word "bag" is the sum of (b=3 + a=2 + g=17) = 22.

For function B-D, the result can be bigger than 10. So in the example, the results are divided by 10 and the remainder is used to conclude the bucket the word is going to.

Comment: I am kinda grasping the concept, so in bucket 2 (out of 10) goes the word user insert! but still even if the final result of the index bucket is 2, what is `3+2+17` ? Are the word bag! I see! Because every letter is coded with a number. Right?

Comment: much clearer, now, I am going to study further from other books as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The slot index must be an integer in range [0,9]. The remainder function (for divisor 10) maps all integers to that range in the most uniform way.

Comment: sorry your reply is too much technical for me

Comment: @Johnsmith: do you understand the first sentence ?

Comment: thank you @YvesDaoust, the first sentence means that the index, the place in the array where the word bag have to go is number 2, so all three letters have to go in position 2, and the remainder is something linked to the so called load factor and resizing I guess

Comment: @Johnsmith: no, I mean *my* first sentence !

Comment: I want to thank you to take time to helping me, now your sentence become clearer to me because of the Aldert reply above. I guess I have to see another book to cover the Hash basis, I am going to upvote you as soon as will get enough reputation to do so(I miss two points), I accepted his reply.